# Copy a ResourceDictionary to a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a ResourceDictionary only containing string keys and string values. Now I want to have a Dictionary< string, string > with the same content.

How would you do that? Whats the fastest solution in C#?

Edit: Fastest in terms of perfomance ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fastest in terms of simplest? Assuming .NET 3.5 (and thus LINQ) I'd use:

```
resourceDictionary.Keys.Cast<string>().ToDictionary
    (x => x,                             // Key selector
     x => (string) resourceDictionary[x] // Value selector
     );
```

Comment: Wow... I didn't even know that was possible. Guess I got a lot to learn ;)
Thank you very much!

Comment: I can highly recommend Jon's book: http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Depth-What-need-master/dp/1933988363/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1239218924&sr=8-1
We have 2 copies at work